# Can the keySet() of a SortedMap always be cast safely to a SortedSet?

Tags: java, collections

I have a [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys. Can I safely cast its keySet() to a [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), without risking an invalid cast exception.

That is, will the following throw?

```
SortedMap<K, V> map = ...;
SortedSet<K> set = (SortedSet<K>) map.keySet();
```

If the answer is "depends on the implementation of SortedMap", is this at a minimum safe for a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)?

Comment: For all those that write "not guaranteed in the documentation", let me point out that the the documentation for SortedSet's keySet() says "The set's iterator returns the keys in ascending order." So even though it is not a "SortedSet", it is a set that is sorted...

Comment: In practice it **is** a SortedSet. But in theory, as long as it is not specified, it doesn't have to (for example, a new SortedSet that is not the internal key set could be created for the iteration - admittedly this would be stupid).

Comment: Correction: even in practice, it is not always a Sortedset as pointed out by one of the answers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For `SortedMap` in general, no as it is not documented in the javadoc.

However, `TreeMap` also implements `NavigableMap`, which uses a `NavigableSet` as a key set and `NavigableSet` extends `SortedSet`...

So what you can do is:

```
NavigableMap<K, V> map = ...; //can be a TreeMap or a ConcurrentSkipListMap
SortedSet<K> set = map.navigableKeySet();
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SortedMap<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
// prints true
System.out.println(treeMap.keySet() instanceof SortedSet);   
// prints false
System.out.println(Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(treeMap).keySet() instanceof SortedSet);
```

So the answer is no.

`TreeMap.keySet()` returns a `SortedSet`, but it's not guaranteed by the javadoc.

The `NavigableMap` interface, which extends `SortedMap`, has a `navigableSet()` method, which returs a `NavigableSet`, which extends `SortedSet`, though.

Answer (score 4):

Given that the documentation doesn't guarantee that it will be a `SortedSet`, even if *current implementations* implement it that way (and I haven't checked that they do), it doesn't mean that it's something you should assume.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not safe since the documentation doesn't say it is. This should be safe though:

`SortedSet<K> set = new TreeSet<K>(map.keySet());`

Comment: Downvote because `new TreeSet` fills the entire set which can be a huge overhead.